# Django/mod_wsgi: First page loads up VERY slowly

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to deploy my first django site through mod_wsgi (on a VPS that also serves PHP pages). Once the first django page is loaded the site runs pretty quick, but loading up that first page is excruciating - at least 15 seconds, sometimes 30 seconds+.

During the first page loadup memory (384MB) is maxed out & other tasks also slow to a crawl. I'm pretty new to django so not quite sure how to solve this. Unfortunately running django through it's own server (as opposed to one that also serves PHP) isn't really feasible.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As answered on #django, likely because embedded mode being used and not daemon mode. Dangers of this described at:

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/03/load-spikes-and-excessive-memory-usage.html